# How to get CSS left property value on second element of anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML Structure:

```
<div id="sqm-id" class="ui-state-disabled ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-slider-disabled ui-disabled">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%;"></a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 100%;"></a>
</div>
```

And I am trying to find `second anchor` inline `left` value and I have tried with this jQuery code but everytime I am getting `undefined` from console.

```
console.log($("#sqm-id").find("a:eq(2)").css("left"));
```

JSFiddle: [Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/pj8qe1e4/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eq()` accesses elements by their index, which is zero-based. Therefore to get the second element you need `:eq(1)`.

```
console.log($("#sqm-id").find("a:eq(1)").css("left"));
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pj8qe1e4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way use `nth-of-type()` the index of each child to match, starting with 1 compared to `.eq()` index it starts from zero array based selector

```
console.log($("#sqm-id").find("a:nth-of-type(2)").css("left"));
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buehjjox/)

Comment: Not `nth-child` but `nth-of-type`.

Comment: @HashemQolami - Thanks, nth-of-type only works in the context you are right

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`eq()` start with zero index and our anchor tag at second position on div so we us `eq(1)`

And if we use `#sqm-id` a it means all anchor tag inside that id `#sqm` no need to use `.find()`

```
console.log($('#sqm-id a').eq(1).css("left"));
```

Comment: This is a code only answer. Please try add some explanation to your answer

Comment: @dotctor explain my answer.

Comment: the review queue was showing the first version of your answer which had no explanation. It is fine now.